# C++: How to find host object from pointer to member variable

Tags: c++, pointers, member, host-object

Here we have our simple node struct which *might* be used to implement a double linked list.

```
template <class T>
struct node {

    node<T> *prev = NULL;
    node<T> *next = NULL;
    T data;
};
```

Supposing we don't know or have reference to a node object/instance, but we do have a pointer to it's *data* member.  T data;

How can the host node object be referenced/found from the pointer to it's *data* member ?

Comment: You can't do it portably. You may find a way hacking about with the `offsetof` macro and `reinterpret_cast<>`ing all the things between `char *` and `node *`, but that's technically undefined behavior. If you need to express a two-way relationship, then use back pointers from each child node to its parent.

Comment: You're asking about how to find the `head` of the list? `T* data;` looks weird BTW.

Comment: Do you really have pointer to the member (`pointer == &node.data`) or do you have the pointer stored in that member (`pointer == node.data`)? If the latter, you cannot find it.

Comment: Sorry,edited! it should read: T data not: T* data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elaborating on StenSoft comment, if you only know the *value* of the `data` member, you won't be able to get the struct containing it.

But if you know its address, say `T** member_addr` you **can** find the `node` :

```
void * ma = static_cast<void *>(member_addr); // convert pointer to void * : legal
intptr_t ima = static_cast<intptr_t>(ma); // convert void * to intptr_t : legal
intptr_t ina = ima - offsetof(struct node, data); // legal by definition of offestof
void * na = static_cast<void *>(ina); // convert intptr_t to void * : legal
struct node *pn = static_cast<node *>(na); // convert void * to pointer : legal provided the initial void * pointer points to a correct object
```

Of course all that is only legal for C++11 or above.